# Error adding local file to docker image with docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I have been working with docker-py, in order to build images and launch containers all in one script. So far it has been very smooth. However, I am currently having issues with the ADD/COPY commands in the Dockerfile string variable.

I need to add a file from the source directory directly into the image. With standard Dockerfiles, I have been able to achieve this successfully, using the docker ADD command. But using docker-py, it throws the exception:

```
Exception: Error building docker image: lstat simrun.py: no such file or directory
```

The script simrun.py is stored in the same directory as the docker-py script, so I cannot understand why I would be receiving this exception. The relative line in dockerpy.py is:

```
 ADD ./simrun.py /opt
```

Is there something that I've missed, or will this functionality just not work in docker-py yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path in the docker build context using the `path` parameter.

See [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html)